# The difference vs what is different?

Tags: word-usage

1. This is **what is different**  between A and B
2. This is **the difference** between A and B

Two sentences above are all correct and have same meaning?

Answer (score -1):

Both sentences mean the same thing and both are grammatically correct.

However the second one is preferred way of saying it.

Comment: No, i think it has two separate meaning. but those can be related to each other